# Enable support for django tags inside js

Tags: javascript, django, visual-studio-code

[image]i currently have to use django template tags inside js script inside a django html template.

Example:

```
<script>

{% for od in object %}
[convertDate("{{ od.date_recorded|date:'Y-m-d' }}"), {{ od.value_recorded }}],
{% endfor %}

</script>
```

visual studio code shows error, is there a way to enable this support?

On the image to not have the red underline error

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Is it because you want to use django tags in a seperate js file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been answered in a different post

[scripting error in django template creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160562/scripting-error-in-django-template-creation)

You can install a visual studio code extension for django templates: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bibhasdn.django-html

This should solve your problem.

Comment: From next time, don't answer duplicate questions, just flag them.